# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on Mac OS

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, c++11, qt5

I've already solved this problem on Windows and some Linux flavors, now is Mac time. It all starts with the following:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Then the solution should be more or less what is pointed in the following links i.e.:

[MySQL for Qt on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579212/mysql-for-qt-on-mac)

[QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on Xubuntu 16.04 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515236/qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-xubuntu-16-04-64bits)

[QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on Ubuntu 15.04 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369480/qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-ubuntu-15-04-64bits)

In the end a new version of (debug and release) the lib should be produced, then is a matter of replacing the old one by the new one and everything will work from now on.

I just did that and the problem is that the new lib (found in `~Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers`), the one just compiled with

```
~/Qt/5.7/clang_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/include/" "LIBS += -L/usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/lib/"
make
```

have the same size as the older (found in `~Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers`). I mean, the lib just compiled is the same as the one already there. And I still get the `QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded`.

Can some one please put some light here? What's going on?

After some time I found ([here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27606-Qt-Mysql-on-Mac-OS-X)) that

```
install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql_debug.dylib
```

and

```
install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/Qt/5.7/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib
```

helps.

I have some understanding of this but I'll leave it open to someone more knowledgeable in the field to give the details.

Answer (score 1):

The critical part is to:

```
~/Qt/5.8/clang_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/include/" "LIBS += -L/usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/lib/" mysql.pro

make
```

And then:

```
cp ~/Qt/5.8/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/ ~/Qt/5.8/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/
```

Comment: 3 weeks getting the same error message.
Installing mysql c connector and compiling qt multiple times
The only step left was the cp command